# Manage javaagent dependencies in a Java project built with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javaagents, open-telemetry

For systems that require a javaagent (say, OpenTelemetry) [the docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#getting-started) often start with "download the agent JAR from this URL and add it to your command line". In a world where library dependencies are handled quite well using Maven Central, with stable versioning etc., the "download a JAR" approach seems primitive and insecure by comparison.

What is the best practice for acquiring javaagent libraries in a project built with Gradle? Is "download this jar" really the current state of the art?

I'm specifically interested in OpenTelemetry right now. If there's an answer (eg. a Gradle plugin) that only works for OpenTelemetry, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have done research, there is one [gradle plugin](https://github.com/ryandens/javaagent-gradle-plugin) available specifically for attaching a maven dependency as javaagent.

Quoting from plugin github repository:

> This Gradle plugin tightly integrates with the Gradle application plugin to make instrumenting your application build by Gradle easy! Simply register the `javaagent-application` plugin and then specify the javaagent you would like to attach in the dependencies block

Example usage with otel java agent can found in the same repository [here](https://github.com/ryandens/javaagent-gradle-plugin/blob/main/example-projects/app/build.gradle.kts)

```
plugins {
    id("com.ryandens.javaagent.example.java-application-conventions")
    id("com.ryandens.javaagent-otel-modification")
    id("com.ryandens.javaagent-application")
}

dependencies {
  otel("io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent:1.13.1")
  otelExtension("io.opentelemetry.contrib:opentelemetry-samplers:1.13.0-alpha")
  otelInstrumentation(project(":custom-instrumentation", "shadow"))
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass.set("com.ryandens.javaagent.example.App")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true", "-Dotel.metrics.exporter=none")
}

/*
  see https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/713
  Currently, tasks that consume the output of the extendedAgent shadowJar task need to be made aware of
  the implicit dependency (https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency)
  due to an issue with the shadowJar plugin
*/
setOf(tasks.distTar, tasks.distZip).forEach {
  it.configure {
    dependsOn(tasks.extendedAgent)
  }
}
```